# WPF Dependency Properties Settings binding doesnt update

Tags: wpf, button, binding, dependency-properties

Ive already been through about 30 different posts and changed how I handle this and it gets closer but still wont work.

I have a Custom Button control in a library, that I am using in Main application. The button displays, handles mouse overs and such, but the dependency property for the text, (or Icon but Ill get to that later) wont update. When I set up the Dependency property with a default value that the only value it displays, it wont display anyhting I set in the designer, or through code.

```
       public static readonly DependencyProperty FileTextProperty;
   //Constructor
       static FileButton()
       {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FileButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(FileButton)));


        // Initialize dependency properties
        FileTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FileText", typeof(string), typeof(FileButton),   new UIPropertyMetadata ("Default File Text")); 
        }

      /// <summary>
    /// The Filename text displayed by the button.
    /// </summary>
    [Description("The text displayed by the button."), Category("Common Properties")]
    public string FileText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FileTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FileTextProperty, value); }
    }
```

here is the XAML (Somewhat abbreviated)

```
                    <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
                        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="GradientStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> 
                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>

                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:FileButton}">
                                    <Grid x:Name="main" MinHeight="38" MaxHeight="38">

                                        <Grid Margin="4,0" Name="DisplayMain">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="fileText" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:FileButton, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=FileText}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,0,0,0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>

                </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0">
                    <local:FileButton Style="{DynamicResource GradientStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I run it the only data displayed on the button is the defaulted text. Even though I know I am setting the Dependency Property. I even when as far as using the binding Path=FileText.Length in the XAML to make sure its reaching it and it is, and it displayed 0 on the button, so it seems like Im not setting the data, even when I manually create the button, and insert it into a container, it still doesnt display what I set it to. (Yes I stepped into it in the debugger to make sure)

Any ideas, its been most of the day trying to figure this out.

PLEASE HELP THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a custom button for this. You can put any content you want inside a Button:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="132,140,168,0" Height="54.96">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Where FileName is a property in a viewmodel you create, which you set to be the DataContext of your Window (or grid or button).

With this [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) setup, when you change FileName in your code, it will automatically display it in your button.

You can still style the button any way you want.

Comment: Well there is actually allot more than just the text, which is why I created the custom button, I have quite a bit more going on, that I ommitted, just becuase it wasnt relevant to this problem. Ill try it that way and see if I can still include everything else.

Comment: You can put a lot more that just text in a button :) you can literally put anything in it, from text and images to listboxes and grids.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using RelativeSource binding instead of `TemplateBinding`

With all else being the same, I would do this

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FileText}" />
```